# How do I make card-columns order horizontally?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have a smart-scrolling list of cards, and while I love the look of `card-columns`, its pretty frustrating that it orders top to bottom, like so:

`1 4 7
2 5 8
3 6 9`

This vertical ordering seems basically useless for anything where the content loads more than a few items. If I have 50 items, some of the least important ones will be at the top!

I've tried some variations using flexbox, but couldn't get anything to work. Does anyone have horizontal ordering working?

Comment: Have you considered using `.card-deck` instead of `.card-columns` or is the masonry effect an absolute must?

Comment: I tried .card-deck, and it didn't look nearly as good.

Comment: do you have any html (& css) code to show and makes see your issue and eventually show you some ways. I guess a javascript solution will be the most and efficient

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As [documented](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/card/#columns), the order of the CSS columns is top to bottom, then left to right so the order of the rendered columns will be..

```
1  3  5
2  4  6
```

There is no way to change the order of CSS columns. It's suggested you use another solution like Masonry. https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/17882

Answer (score 13):

Found here a nice and basic solution (not directly for bootstrap) to set a masonry vertical or horizontal with css http://w3bits.com/flexbox-masonry/

I will give a test and give feedback how to use with bootstrap 4.

**for horizontal usage**:

```
.masonry { 
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  margin-left: -8px; /* Adjustment for the gutter */
}

.masonry-brick {
  flex: auto;
  height: 250px;
  min-width: 150px;
  margin: 0 8px 8px 0; /* Some gutter */
}
.masonry-brick {
  &:nth-child(4n+1){
     width: 250px;
  }
  &:nth-child(4n+2){
     width: 325px;
  }
  &:nth-child(4n+3){
     width: 180px;
  }
  &:nth-child(4n+4){
     width: 380px;
  }
}
```

**for vertical usage**:

```
.masonry { 
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  max-height: 800px;
  margin-left: -8px; /* Adjustment for the gutter */
}

.masonry-brick {
  margin: 0 8px 8px 0; /* Some gutter */
}
```

Comment: Wow this looks legit. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

The only thing that worked for me was integrating "bricklayer"

- https://github.com/ademilter/bricklayer

Comment: Cards not ordered properly when in single column