# Bootstrap 4 order Masonry-like column cards horizontal instead of vertical

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-4

Is it possible to order **Bootstrap 4 Cards** from left to right when wrapped in `.card-columns`?

Top to bottom (default):

```
1 3 5
2 4 6
```

Left to right:

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
```

Because of the varying height it is necessary for me to use an Masonry-like grid.

Comment: you can do that using **css-flexbox**

Comment: ^ Open the `_variables.scss` file and find the `$enable-flex` variable. Change it from `false` to `true`.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The order of the CSS columns is top to bottom, then left to right so the order of the rendered columns will be..

```
1  3  5
2  4  6
```

There is no way to change the order of CSS columns. It's suggested you use another solution like Masonry. https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/17882

Also, enabling [flexbox won't help](http://www.codeply.com/go/aAdbASwxR1) because Bootstrap `card-deck` uses CSS columns (not flexbox) for the masonry effect. You can however use the `card-deck` and flexbox for equal height cards: http://www.codeply.com/go/YFFFWHVoRB

Another option is to use the [grid along with flexbox](http://www.codeply.com/go/jbcgzs2Nzq) instead of the `card-deck`:

You can use the new `d-flex` class to [eliminate the extra CSS](http://www.codeply.com/go/FEW9U4ZElQ):

```
<div class="col-sm-4 d-flex pb-3">
    <div class="card card-block">
        Card. I'm just a simple card-block.
    </div>
</div>
```

Related:
[How do I make card-columns order horizontally?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38704826/how-do-i-make-card-columns-order-horizontally/38705192)